# Uncaught TypeError: variableProducts.select2 is not a function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I get this console error when I load a single product page in WooCommerce 8.3.0:

```
Uncaught TypeError: variableProducts.select2 is not a function
at gradaInitSelect2 (ozark.js?ver=1.0.0:4:133)
at ozark.js?ver=1.0.0:7:1
at ozark.js?ver=1.0.0:40:319
```

[ozark.js file for reference](https://pastebin.com/K0mFnyYb)

I searched around for related topics and it seemed like multiple instances of jQuery being loaded could be the culprit so I made sure that wasn't the case. Otherwise, I'm stuck on what to do.

On a side note, this started happening once I upgraded to WooCommerce 8.3.0 from 8.2.2. Before the upgrade, I had no issues.